# Laravel 7, use auth guard only

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am using PHP Laravel 7, I'm working on a project for which i have to use authentication from outer source, API's are provided for signup and login. I just want to know is it possible that i can use the authentication of Laravel and use my custom login and signup and can i use authentication guard for stopping the URL routes.

I had already created pages for login and register so far but haven't added authentication yet.

```
    if (Auth::check()) {
    // The user is logged in...
}
```

I want something like this for custom login in.

Answer (score 0):

You can receive all the data from your API and then manually create a user and login them.

A piece of example from a real application

```php
$user = User::firstOrCreate(['vk_id' => $data['user_id']]);
auth()->login($user, true); //true is to remember them
```

After that you can add any data to any field you want:

```php
$user->position = 'ceo';
$user->save();
```

Or any other logic you want.

You can add this logic to your auth register or login controller, or create a separate one.
Virtually, built-in Auth controllers are the same controller with their own logic to work with a database and sessions.

But login the user manually using `->login()` function.